# do not output specific div if something is null using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am making database query.

```
let link = something from the database;
let output = `
   <div>
      ...
   <div>
   <div>
      ...
   <div>
   <div>
      <iframe src="${link}"></iframe>
   </div>
   <div>
      <div>
         ...
      </div>
   <div>
`;
$('#table').html(output);
```

The link could be `empty` then I do not want to output the highlighted div. I do not know a "cool" way of doing that.

Comment: Why not using a simple if-statement?

Comment: As I say there are multiple div inside output string

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It might be best to take the Tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour You may also consider using a Loop of your data set and conditionally, with an `if` statement, add the html to your variable. It would be best to provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example We need an example of the data that jQuery will be working with.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  var links = [
    "Url 1",
    "",
    "Url 3",
    "Url 4",
    "Url 5"
  ];

  $.each(links, function(i, link) {
    if (link != "") {
      $("<div>").html($("<iframe>", {
        src: link
      })).appendTo("#table");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="table">
</div>
```

You will want to iterate your data and conditionally add the HTML.

See More:

- https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you don't want to display the iframe, if `link` is set to `null`.

This is one of many ways how you could do it:

```js
let link = 'Change me to null';
link ??= `
   <div>
      <iframe src="${link}"></iframe>
   </div>
`;

let output = `
   <div>
      ...
   <div>
   <div>
      ...
   <div>
`;
output += link;
output += `
   <div>
      <div>
         ...
      </div>
   <div>
`;
$('#table').html(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="table"></div>
```